# how to work with setstate inside a function returns a widget?

Tags: flutter

I am using a method in the same class with the build method
and this method contains a drop-down button but it does not show the
new value although I am using the set state method
how can I solve this

```
NamedPropertiesFields.add(addNamedProperty(NamedPropertiesFields.length));
```

and this is where I called my function addNamedProperty which returns a widget

```
  Widget addNamedProperty(int index){
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        flex: 4,
        child: TextFormField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              print(value);
              properties[index] = value;
            });
          },
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorText: true
                ? null
                : 'You must enter a property name',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Property',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 16,
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 4,
        child: TextFormField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              print(value);
              values[index] = value;
            });
          },
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorText:isValuesVlaid[index]
                ? null
                : 'The property must have value',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'value',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: You have to show more code to get help